# Migrating WordPress from Windows Server 2008 R2 (IIS v7.5) to CentOS

Tags: server, apache, iis, linux, windows

The agency I work for have purchased a new server, bringing our total up to 4. The 3 servers we had previously are all running Windows Server 2008 R2, whereas this new one is running CentOS, exclusively for running more PHP based sites as opposed to the ASP.NET sites we were developing previously.

Myself and the other developer have tried the standard migration techniques we can come across, including making a copy of the installation directory and moving that to the new server, as well as changing the domain references within the mySQL database. I am thinking that the problem could possibly lie with the fact we have changed the website from a *.co.uk* subdomain to a *.agency* subdomain, however the two TLDs (*.co.uk* and *.agency*) are associated with separate servers respectively.

Whilst editing the databases, we have found that there were around 5 backslashes (\\) by every references, thus causing an invalid reference.

We removed these backslashes, and it seemed to work fine... until we disabled the current subdomain. Then the website collapsed and showed no styling or anything.

We edited the SQL file again after this, and the server seems to have added the backslashes back into the database, and add the references back.

The website is using the Themify Landing theme, so could this possibly be the problem?

Both of the servers in question are also using Plesk, and they are also using the same version of mySQL. Could the configuration on either of these be the problem? We are very quickly running out of ideas.

Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to rectify the issue so I hand over to you.

I would appreciate any help you guys could provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this.

The Duplicator kept throwing up 500 errors, so I scrapped that idea.

For migrating the database and theme/plugin folders, I used the [All-in-One WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) plugin.

I then used the built in [export](https://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen) and import tools in order to populate the pages and carry across posts.

I would recommend using this method for anybody experiencing the same problems as myself, as this method seemed to work.

The only issue I encountered with this method was that the menu bar had duplicated all of the links.

**Update:** I discovered why the menu had duplicated the links and I had to use the built in import/export tools.

The problem I had was that the server-side PHP settings were causing the plugin to import incorrectly. If you use the following settings for your server-side PHP, it works like a dream:

**memory_limit:** 128m

**max_execution_time:** 7200

**post_max_size:** 64m

**upload_max_filesize:** 32m

I have used the above PHP settings on around 5 sites within the space of a week, 3 of which have since gone live.

Answer (score 0):

On your current website add [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/)(a free plugin) and create a new package, that you can use in the new environment. It will give you several options on Storage, Archiving and Installer script.

Comment: I will give this a try in the morning and then reply if it still doesn't work.